# References regarding rules for multidimensional histograms

Tags: data-visualization, references, density-function, histogram, density-estimation

Can someone give me references on the theory of histograms applied to multivariate data? Are there any rules like the one dimensional Freedman-Diaconis available for the high dimensional case? What are the most common drawbacks? I'm planning to use the histogram to do density estimation.

Comment: For the purpose of data visualization, the high-dimensional case might be limited to 3D (or 4D using faceted plots or small multiples), right?